# Rails 5 and Knock gem: can't authenticate users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, jwt

Steps to reproduce:

**Bundler install** the following Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.3.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.0'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
# gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
gem 'knock'


# Use ActiveStorage variant
# gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

# Use Rack CORS for handling Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS), making cross-origin AJAX possible
gem 'rack-cors'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end


# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

**Generate the User model, the Knock config and the Knock token_controller**

```
rails g model User
rails g knock:install
rails g knock:token_controller User
```

**User model:**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_secure_password

    def self.from_token_request request
        username = request.params["auth"] && request.params["auth"]["username"]
        self.find_by username: username
    end
end
```

**UserTokenController**

```
class UserTokenController < Knock::AuthTokenController

    skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

    private
    def auth_params
        params.require(:auth).permit(:username, :password)
    end
end
```

After the db is seeded with an user, I attempt to post matching credentials with Postman. The server responds with error 500 and the following log:

```
Started POST "/api/user_token" for ::1 at 2018-04-23 13:18:14 +0200
   (0.1ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
  ↳ /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
Processing by UserTokenController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"auth"=>{"username"=>"majje", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
majje
  User Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."username" = ? LIMIT ?  [["username", "majje"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/models/user.rb:7
true
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."username" = ? LIMIT ?  [["username", "majje"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/models/user.rb:8
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 86ms (ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)



TypeError (no implicit conversion of nil into String):

jwt (1.5.6) lib/jwt.rb:75:in `digest'
jwt (1.5.6) lib/jwt.rb:75:in `sign_hmac'
jwt (1.5.6) lib/jwt.rb:36:in `sign'
jwt (1.5.6) lib/jwt.rb:96:in `encoded_signature'
jwt (1.5.6) lib/jwt.rb:106:in `encode'
knock (2.1.1) app/model/knock/auth_token.rb:14:in `initialize'
knock (2.1.1) app/controllers/knock/auth_token_controller.rb:22:in `new'
knock (2.1.1) app/controllers/knock/auth_token_controller.rb:22:in `auth_token'
knock (2.1.1) app/controllers/knock/auth_token_controller.rb:8:in `create'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `send_action'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:194:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:42:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (5.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:132:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:41:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:22:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:34:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (5.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (5.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:23:in `instrument'
activesupport (5.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `instrument'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:256:in `process_action'
activerecord (5.2.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:134:in `process'
actionview (5.2.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:32:in `process'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:191:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:252:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:52:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:34:in `serve'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:52:in `block in serve'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:35:in `each'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:35:in `serve'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:840:in `call'
rack (2.0.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.4) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:38:in `call'
rack (2.0.4) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
activerecord (5.2.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:559:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:98:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:61:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
railties (5.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (5.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `tagged'
railties (5.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.0.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.2.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:127:in `call'
rack (2.0.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
railties (5.2.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:524:in `call'
puma (3.11.4) lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
puma (3.11.4) lib/puma/server.rb:632:in `handle_request'
puma (3.11.4) lib/puma/server.rb:446:in `process_client'
puma (3.11.4) lib/puma/server.rb:306:in `block in run'
puma (3.11.4) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

I've tried to follow several guides posted by others.
I've also tried the documentation.
And lastly, I've tried googling in hopes of finding someone with the same problem. The results made me feel kinda lonely. Anyone have a clue what the problem might be?

Comment: Did you modify anything in the knock config?

Comment: Nothing is modified in the knock config.

Comment: I dug through the source for that version of JWT, the method that it fails on wants 3 arguments, the first is created and the second two should be strings. Somehow your code (or the gem) is not passing in one of the last 2 args. Do you have email addresses to auth against? Can you remove the username customization and see if it still errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that there is a line in your config/initializers/knock.rb

```
  # config.token_secret_signature_key = -> { Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base }
```

In rails 5.2 ,there is no Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base,that's why the exception tells that it expects a String but a nil.So you can uncomment it like this:

```
config.token_secret_signature_key = -> { "yoursercet" }
```

You can read this [issue](https://github.com/nsarno/knock/issues/205)

Answer (score 3):

As you are using Rails 5.2 (which comes with a [new approach to handle app secrets](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/5_2_release_notes.html#credentials)), you need to edit `config/initializers/knock.rb` like this:

```
config.token_secret_signature_key = -> { Rails.application.credentials.read }
```

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment this line in `config/initializers/knock.rb`

`# config.token_secret_signature_key = -> { Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base }`

and update `Rails.applications.secrets.secret_key_base`

to  **config.token_secret_signature_key = -> { Rails.application.credentials.secret_key_base }**

good luck (y)